# I have an Enumerable Where method, how to change it into non-linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of numbers to 75, and I'm showing it by using a Linq `where` clause. I'm asking is to transfer a code of linq to non linq. Using a list ?

```
playerhand = new int[75];
numbers = new int[75];

for (int i = 0; i < 75; i++)
{
    sClass.numbers[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Here's my linq `where` code snippet. Please help me to change it not to use any Linq:

```
Console.WriteLine("Player Hand : ");
Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(", ", sClass.playerhand.Where(x => x != 0)));
Console.WriteLine("Bingo Numbers : ");
Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Comment: There is no LINQ here. There is no `.Where` here.

Comment: @Llama Sorry, I already edit the code.

Comment: @llama no`Where()` `as` in not `Any()Where()` at `All()`?

Comment: @CaiusJard Indeed.

Comment: @Llama Hello I have another question. Are u there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need somewhere to collect the items. Since we don't know how many items will match, we should use a `List<T>`:

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();
```

Then you need to loop through each item and add the matching ones to the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sClass.playerhand.Length; ++i)
{
    if (sClass.playerhand[i] != 0)
    {
        values.Add(sClass.playerhand[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `values` list in place of your existing LINQ expression:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(", ", values));
```