# Using LINQ's Where, Convert to Non-LINQ's

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code for my method a `where` clause.

```
playerhand[i] = numbers[0];
numbers = numbers.Where((source, index) => index != 0).ToArray();
```

Then so far I tried to make it a Non-Linq. I don't if I'm doing it right. Please correct me, there's no error but it displays a ton of zeros. I also refer to this: [I have an Enumerable Where method, how to change it into non-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864960/i-have-an-enumerable-where-method-how-to-change-it-into-non-linq), but mine has a `Source, index`

```
playerhand[i] = numbers[0];
for (int n = 0; n < 75 - i; n++)
{
    if (playerhand[i] == numbers[n])
        numbers[n] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your interpretation of the original? To me, it says "ignore the first element, create an array with everything else"; is my interpretation wrong? The trick is to figure out what the original does, then replicate it. I'm honestly not sure what your second version is doing, or why - it looks nothing at all like the original

Comment: Does this code in performance critical code? If not, then don't convert to loop as it lose expressiveness. I would write it as `number.Skip(1).ToArray()` - this is even more expressive and a bit more performant

Comment: @FarzinKanzi It's a collection of integers yes, And then I tried it to make it a Non-Linq but a ton of zeros is printing.

Comment: @JL0PD The `.Skip` is a Linq...

Comment: @CsTa genuine question: what is it you're trying to achieve with a non-LINQ solution? `.Skip(1).ToArray()` seems pretty clear, and is unlikely to be a performance problem in any real scenario - although more frugal versions (like the span version) are available

Comment: @MarcGravell It's a requirements. But I do appreciate the `.Skip(1).ToArray() ` Actually it works.

Comment: @CsTa a requirement of whom, and for what reason? Not all "requirements" are genuinely requirements, and any reasonable client is open to discussion when informed that they're being daft. The art is in understanding **what they're trying to achieve** via their stated requirement, and deliver *that*. Usually, the client isn't the subject expert, which is why they're talking to you. You are allowed to challenge assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer makes the following assumptions:

- The question is not about how to remove the first element of an array.
- The question is about how to construct an equivalent of a Linq query using basic loop constructs.

So with this assumptions:

The query uses the following  overload of the Where method:

```cs
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,int,bool> predicate);
```

where predicate is a `Func<TSource,Int32,Boolean>`

So it takes as a parameter a predicate, using both the current value and the index of the element of the collection which is enumerated.

A predicate is simply a function that returns a boolean, to be used for condition checking.

The following Linq query

```cs
numbers = numbers.Where((e, i) => predicate(e, i)).ToArray();
```

can be replaced by:

```cs
var result = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    if( predicate(numbers[i], i) )
    {
        result.Add(numbers[i]);
    }
}

numbers = result.ToArray();
```

Indeed, when materialized, the Where query will do just that: take each element one by one, and check via a predicate if the element (and in this case its index) should be added to the newly constructed collection.

So in this specific case, the query would become:

```cs
var result = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    if( i != 0 )
    {
        result.Add(numbers[i]);
    }
}

numbers = result.ToArray();
```

In this example, the predicate just uses the index, but generally it could use both the index and the current value.

Comment: Why you start your loop from zero and then check the `if(i != 0)` ? you could start it from 1.

Comment: Because the Linq Where query is using a predicate, and I wanted to use the same predicate in order to show the correspondance between the Linq query and the for loop.
This is the only interest this code have.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I edited my answer, so it should be more clear why starting from 1 would makes no sense in that context.

Comment: I'd appreciate ur effort @LaurentGabiot So I will consider this a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to create a new array that omits the first value. So... do that? Perhaps the most frugal way is via a span:

```cs
numbers = numbers.AsSpan(1).ToArray();
```

or (earlier runtimes)

```cs
numbers = new Span<TheType>(numbers, 1, numbers.Length - 1).ToArray();
```

You could also just create the array in a temporary variable and use `CopyTo`

Comment: It errors the `AsSpans` , Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'AsSpan' and no accessible extension method 'AsSpan' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @CsTa did you see my "or (earlier runtimes)"? Also: what runtime are you using? If it is older, you may need a package-reference (nuget) to System.Memory; reference (also shows which runtimes that API is in, and the namespace (`System`)): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=net-5.0#System_MemoryExtensions_AsSpan__1___0___System_Int32_

Comment: @CsTa You need to reference `System.Memory` and open `System` namespace. `AsSpan` extensions method is supporter on .net framework and netcore, you don't need to create it explicitly

Comment: @MarcGravell I think i'm not allowed to use other namespace `System`

Comment: I get it. But we're not allowed to use other namespaces `System`

Comment: The span solution is interesting and probably pretty much as performant as the traditional Array.Copy approach. But I imagine given that this is pretty clearly homework, that the professor expects the classic for loop explicitly written.

Comment: While this answer is relevant in a general sense, it is off-topic. I believe the question is not about "How do I remove the first element of an array" but about the correspondence of Linq queries and basic loop constructs for collection manipulation. Maybe @Cs Ta can give us more insights?

Comment: @CsTa you realize that `Array` is in the same namespace (`System`), right? I mean, you could *try* to do this without arrays, but it seems a daft goal

Comment: @MarcGravell Thankyou for the effort i'd appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I already figure it out. Using a classic for loop. Here's my code

```
for (int n = 0; n < 75; n++)
        {
            if (numbers[n] != 0)
            {
                playerhand[i] = numbers[n];
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < numbers.Length; n++)
        {
            if (numbers[n] == playerhand[i])
            {
                numbers[n] = 0;
            }
        }
```

All your answers are correct. Thank you for the effort guys.

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand your question, you want to do this:

```
numbers = numbers.Where((source, index) => index != 0).ToArray();
```

but without using linq. The code above only removes the first element of the array. With an array we have not `Add` or `Remove` methods So you can change your array to a list and easily remove the element you want:

```
List<int> numList = numbers.ToList();
numList.RemoveAt(0);
numbers = numList.ToArray();
```

**Edit**

This removes the first item without using linq:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{
       numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
}
Array.Resize(ref numbers, numbers.Length - 1);
```

With the for loop we shift every number to its next one, and then after resize the array to remove the last item.

Comment: This code also use a `System.Linq` ?

Comment: You are right. I'm going to edit or remove it.

Comment: Please edit to `Non-Linq`

Comment: This is an awfully inefficient solution.